# View CPU & Memory Usage in Azure AKS Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-aks

Hello I upgraded my Azure AKS cluster from 1.12.6 to 1.14.7.

On version 1.12.6 when I connected to Dashboard in a web browser(by az aks browse) I view CPU & Memory Usage

Now on new version I cannot see it

I have to enable something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your issue is an existing problem and it's still on the way to be fixed. You can take a look at the [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/4145) in Github. If it's necessary for you, please use the version 1.12.6 as before.